# How to create dynamic columns using prepared statements in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, dynamic-sql, prepared-statement

I have 4 tables related to each other.

Table location:

```
CREATE TABLE `location` (
  `id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

INSERT INTO `location` (`id`, `name`) VALUES
(1, 'Dallas'),
(2, 'Boston'),
(3, 'Houston');
```

Table item:

```
CREATE TABLE `item` (
 `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `brand` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

INSERT INTO `item` (`id`, `brand`) VALUES
(1, 'Nissan Almera M/T 2009-2015'),
(2, 'Toyota Corolla A/T 2005-2012'),
(3, 'Nissan Terra A/T 2010-2017'),
(4, 'Suzuki Esteem M/T 1980-1990'),
(5, 'Toyota Fortuner A/T 2014-2020');
```

Table item_in:

```
CREATE TABLE `item_in` (
  `id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `location_id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `item_id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `quantity` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

INSERT INTO `item_in` (`id`, `location_id`, `item_id`, `quantity`) VALUES
(1, 1, 1, 1000),
(2, 1, 2, 500),
(3, 2, 2, 200),
(4, 2, 2, 300),
(5, 3, 3, 300),
(6, 1, 3, 800),
(7, 3, 5, 300),
(8, 3, 4, 400);
```

Table item_out:

```
CREATE TABLE `item_out` (
  `id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `location_id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `item_id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `quantity` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

INSERT INTO `item_out` (`id`, `location_id`, `item_id`, `quantity`) VALUES
(1, 1, 2, 20),
(2, 1, 1, 25),
(3, 2, 2, 25),
(4, 3, 3, 25),
(5, 3, 5, 10),
(6, 3, 4, 15),
(7, 1, 1, 200),
(8, 2, 2, 50);
```

Using dynamic SQL, I was able to get the individual remaining quantities per item based on their location and item (item_in quantity subtracted by item_out quantity) and have the location names as columns. (see code below):

```
SET @sql = NULL, @sql1 = NULL, @sql2 = NULL;

SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT
          CONCAT('SUM(CASE WHEN `location_id` = ''',`location_id`, ''' THEN quantity END) AS ',`name`))
          INTO @sql1
          FROM item_in
          JOIN location on location.id = item_in.location_id;
        
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT
          CONCAT('SUM(CASE WHEN `location_id` = ''',`location_id`, ''' THEN quantity END) AS ',`name`))
          INTO @sql2
          FROM item_out
          JOIN location on location.id = item_out.location_id;
          
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT item.brand AS Item, IFNULL(item_in.Dallas, 0) - IFNULL(item_out.Dallas, 0) AS Dallas, IFNULL(item_in.Boston, 0) - IFNULL(item_out.Boston, 0) AS Boston, IFNULL(item_in.Houston, 0) - IFNULL(item_out.Houston, 0) AS Houston FROM item LEFT JOIN (SELECT item_in.item_id, ', @sql1, ' FROM item_in
                    GROUP BY item_in.item_id) AS item_in ON item.id = item_in.item_id LEFT JOIN (SELECT item_out.item_id, ', @sql2, ' FROM item_out
                    GROUP BY item_out.item_id) AS item_out ON item.id = item_out.item_id');
                    
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

**Result**:

```
Item                         | Dallas | Boston | Houston
Nissan Almera M/T 2009-2015        775        0         0                           
Toyota Corolla A/T 2005-2012       480      425         0
Nissan Terra A/T 2010-2017         800        0       275
Suzuki Esteem M/T 1980-1990          0        0       385
Toyota Fortuner A/T 2014-2020        0        0       290
```

My question, how do I go about changing the code so that the location name columns is displayed dynamically instead of hardcoding them manually in the query since users can add new locations anytime? if anyone can take a look at my code, i'd really appreciate the help. The only part I'm having trouble is how to not hardcode these lines and do them dynamically:

```
IFNULL(item_in.Dallas, 0) - IFNULL(item_out.Dallas, 0) AS Dallas, IFNULL(item_in.Boston, 0) - IFNULL(item_out.Boston, 0) AS Boston, IFNULL(item_in.Houston, 0) - IFNULL(item_out.Houston, 0) AS Houston
```

Comment: I'm afraid neither MySQL nor MariaDB have a solution for pivoting in SQL.  PostgreSQL, Oracle and another obscure DB do.  But this can easily be handled by most clients.  Which is yours?

Comment: @GerardH.Pille im using MySQL. do you have any suggestions or tips on how to best do this? as this is the only way I could think of. appreciate you looking into my problem though. thanks man.

Comment: Well, for any suggestions I would need to know what client software needs the pivot result.

Comment: im using XAMPP. im not sure if that answers your question though. @GerardH.Pille

Comment: No it doesn't.  Your client could be PHP or Perl.  Which one executes the query?

Comment: @GerardH.Pille I'm using PHP. i already updated the post to make it more readable and concise. i also included an MRE so you can recreate the table if you need to. hope you can take a look into this. thanks in advance!

Comment: I'll give it a try later in the day.  I thought you'd cracked it but there's indeed still some hardcoding left.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille thanks in advance man!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a possible solution in PHP:

```
  $link = mysqli_connect("p:192.168.3.2", "ghp", "azerty", "test");

  if (!$link) {
     error_log ( "Error: Unable to connect to MySQL. "
                  . mysqli_connect_errno() );
     header('HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error');
     exit;
  }

  // store the items in an array, will be used as rows
  $itema = array();
  $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($link);
  if (mysqli_stmt_prepare(
        $stmt,
        "select id, brand from item")) {
     $count = 0;
     $lid = $lname = "";
     if (mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)) {
        mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $lid, $lname);
        while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {
           $count += 1;
           $itema[$lid] = $lname;
        }
     } else {
        error_log ( "Error: execute - "
                    . mysqli_errno($link) . " - " . mysqli_error($link));
        header('HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error');
     }
     if ($count < 1) {
        header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden');
     }
     mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
  } else {
     error_log ( "Error: prepare - "
                  . mysqli_errno($link) . " - " . mysqli_error($link));
     header('HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error');
  }

  // store the locations in an array, will be used as columns
  $loca = array();
  $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($link);
  if (mysqli_stmt_prepare(
        $stmt,
        "select id, name from location")) {
     $count = 0;
     $lid = $lname = "";
     if (mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)) {
        mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $lid, $lname);
        while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {
           $count += 1;
           $loca[$lid] = $lname;
        }
     } else {
        error_log ( "Error: execute - "
                    . mysqli_errno($link) . " - " . mysqli_error($link));
        header('HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error');
     }
     if ($count < 1) {
        header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden');
     }
     mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
  } else {
     error_log ( "Error: prepare - "
                  . mysqli_errno($link) . " - " . mysqli_error($link));
     header('HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error');
  }

  // store the remaining quantities in an array, for the table cells
  $data = array();
  $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($link);
  if (mysqli_stmt_prepare(
        $stmt,
        "select
           location_id,
           item_id,
           sum(quantity)
           from (
             select location_id, item_id, quantity from item_in
             union all
             select location_id, item_id, -quantity from item_out
           ) s
           group by location_id, item_id")) {
     $count = 0;
     $lid = $iid = $q = 0;
     if (mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)) {
        mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $lid, $iid, $q);
        while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {
           $count += 1;
           $data[$lid][$iid] = $q;
        }
     } else {
        error_log ( "Error: execute - "
                    . mysqli_errno($link) . " - " . mysqli_error($link));
        header('HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error');
     }
     if ($count < 1) {
        header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden');
     }
     mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
  } else {
     error_log ( "Error: prepare - "
                  . mysqli_errno($link) . " - " . mysqli_error($link));
     header('HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error');
  }

  // show the results in a table
  print("<html><head>\n");
  print("<style>
          table,th,td {
            border: 1px solid black;
            border-collapse: collapse;
          }
         </style></head><body>\n");
  print("<table>\n");
  print("<tr><th>&nbsp;");
  foreach($loca as $i => $value) {
    print("<th align=right>" . $value);
  }
  foreach($itema as $i => $value) {
    print("<tr><td style='font-weight:bold;'>" . $value);
    foreach($loca as $j => $value) {
      print("<td align=right>" . $data[$j][$i]  );
    }
    print("\n");
  }
  print("</table></body></html>\n");
```

Comment: sorry for the delayed response. thanks so much for helping me with my problem man. i really appreciate it!